# is having all ram slot filled remove some overclocking room?

Tags: cpu, memory, overclocking

I have 4x 2gig, filling out all my ram slot.

Does it automatically mean that I wont be able to overclock as much as having only 2 filled?

Using Asus p7p55d-e pro motherboard
Intel i5 760
and 2x Corsair XMS3 CMX4GX3M2A1600C7 4GB DDR3 2X2GB DDR3-1600 CL 7-8-7-20

it seem I can only reach 19x 200mhz (3.8ghz)

I can't do 20x 200 or 21x190 to get 4ghz, maybe I got a bad cpu batch...

Comment: It should not matter. <br/>
BTW, what are you overclocking when you have 8G RAM ?

Comment: @Patkos Csaba, believe me, it all matters.  ANY THING you put in your system has the chance of helping or hurting an overclock, it just depends on the specific system and the hardware therein.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your processor.  Some AMD processors had issues with bottlenecking with all RAM slots filled (specifically the C2 Phenom) but the C3 fixed this.  I don't think Intels have this issue.

edit: Based on your additional CPU info it shouldn't be an issue.